# Securing VGA Output Plus Audio From An iPad

Tags: ipad, hdmi, vga-adapter, lightning

As part of a retrofitting project for my church, I purchased a variety of equipment.  The minister has a recent model iPad with Lightning port.  I purchased a Lightning to HDMI adapter to get sound and video.  The church's overhead projector, for which there is no budget to replace right now, only handles a VGA input or composite input.  I purchased a Belkin HDMI to VGA adapter that has a 3.5 mm output so I could patch into the audio system's soundboard.

When I hooked this up to my iPad, it initially wanted to work.  It didn't though.  Nothing would play through the lash-up of cables.  I've tested the cables individually for the roles they play and they work.  Together they cannot get me VGA video and sound to run to a mixing board.

Is there a way to accomplish this through cabling?  Am I missing something or is this a dead end?

Comment: Thunderbolt is not used by iOS devices. Lightning is. Thunderbolt is a mac thing.

Comment: Also, you do not need the Belkin vga adaptar. Use the [Apple One](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MD825AM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter) then use the built in output for audio on the iPad. This has worked on all but beta versions of iOS 10.3.3

Comment: I suppose I should go ahead and correct my brain fart above.  I meant Lightning.  If I correct that would you please convert your comments to an answer that I'll go ahead and accept?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure there wasn’t some weird setup going on, thanks for clarifying. I have added the following as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Apple Lightning to VGA Adapter](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MD825AM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter) works, and when paired with a 3.5mm audio cord plugged directly into the output on the iPad, will allow for sound and video output.

If you have a system that allows for digital audio, it is possible to use a DSP for passthrough from the iPad to the Sound Board, however one usually runs for around $100-$1400.